# how to join different tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, subquery

i tried searching related query statement and applied but not work.

i am trying to join all tables for my api in one GET call and i am not able to perform it. query failed and get errors.

My query looks like this for the table i have shown.

```
SELECT projects.*, images.*, rewards.*, shipping.* 
FROM projects 
LEFT JOIN rewards ON rewards.projects_id = projects.id 
LEFT INNER JOIN rewards ON rewards.id = shipping.reward_id 
LEFT JOIN images ON projects.id = images.project_id 
WHERE projects.id = 1
```

[image]

i want to join rewards and shipping with all table, project to rewards has relationship of one to many and rewards to shipping also one to many. How can i combine in all this in one query?? i am also trying sub queries but i have no idea how to make the queries in these table.
Please explain me how would it work in sub-queries or in join?
If it is not good practice please explain me others technique also.

**UPDATE**

i tried it like this using subquery it said unknown  column shipping

```
SELECT projects.*, rewards.*, images.image, shipping = (SELECT *
FROM shipping
WHERE shipping.reward_id IN (SELECT * FROM rewards WHERE rewards.project_id = 1)) 
FROM projects JOIN rewards ON rewards.project_id = projects.id 
LEFT JOIN images ON projects.id = images.project_id 
WHERE projects.id = 1
```

Comment: Where you fin this `LEFT INNER JOIN` ?
please share `show create table` for your tables and the final result you want to have

Comment: If you are going to select all data from those four tables, you will not know which image to combine with which reward, and so the result will be that every image will be combined with every reward. You should provide sample data and the output you would like to have for those sample data.

Comment: Hi. Please format that code reasonably. Also read & act on [mcve]. And read an introduction to relational databases--you question just asks for one. Also google SO for variations on your title/question for examples.

Comment: ok, i  will edit it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has several syntax issues. To join in all tables, you would write:

```
SELECT    projects.title, rewards.price, images.images, shipping.shipping
FROM      projects
LEFT JOIN images ON images.project_id = projects.id
LEFT JOIN rewards ON rewards.project_id = projects.id
LEFT JOIN shipping ON shipping.rewards_id = rewards.id
WHERE     projects.id = 1
```

... but be aware that if you have many images and many rewards for the same project, this query will produce all the combinations of images and rewards, because your database schema does not define which image belongs with which reward.

Comment: Thank you, it work. that are the sample tables and query. it work in my real query also. But Table data is repeated as i have 1:m relationship. can you suggest me how to filter that??? if not i will do it in php.

Comment: If you are asking to get `null` values instead of repeated values, then yes, you should do that in PHP. Although it is possible to do in SQL, it is not the role of SQL, and will make the query rather complex and the output hard to order. Do it in PHP.